# Browse a whole folder in C

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to list all the contents of a folder (including subfolder and its files)
Like ls -R with Linux
(I am using windows 10)

I already have this basic code with "dirent.h"

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main()
{
DIR *rep ;
struct dirent *file ;

rep = opendir ("c:\test") ;
if (rep != NULL)
{
while (file = readdir(rep))
printf ("%s\n", file->d_name) ;
(void) closedir (rep) ;
}
return 0;
}
```

It lists the contents of a folder well but does not browse the sub-folders
For example it could browse a whole hard drive
like C: /

I can't use d_type for detect if the content is a file or a folder
Because with windows the struct is:

```c
struct dirent
{
    long        d_ino;      /* Always zero. */
    unsigned short  d_reclen;   /* Always zero. */
    unsigned short  d_namlen;   /* Length of name in d_name. */
    char        d_name[260]; /* [FILENAME_MAX] */ /* File name. */
};
```

So I'm stuck on this problem, if anyone has an idea, or even a code

---

COMPILER: MinGW32 1.5.0

Comment: You should `stat` the entries of each directory to see if they are directories themselves. Then recursively `readdir` any entries that are directories.

Comment: What does your tutorial or book or class notes say about backslash in a string?

Comment: Use `stat(d_name)` to get the info. That's what we used to have to do before `d_type` was added

Comment: And on Windows I recommend you use the native Windows function for iterating over directories and files, like [`FindFirstFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and [`FindNextFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea).

Comment: What compiler do you use? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: What's stopping you from iterating into each directory? Do you have an algorithm for doing so? Do you know how to tell which entries are directories? What do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Other considerations aside, the solution to this is likely to be a recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of directory list for Windows.

I used Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 to build. It works as a Unicode Windows application. That is files and folders having name with non ASCII characters are handled correctly.

To achieve that, I used Windows typical data types and functions:

```
char    -> WCHAR
strcpy  -> wcscpy
strcat  -> wcscat
strncmp -> wcsncmp
printf  -> wprintf
```

Depending on the compiler you use, you may use the standard data types and functions.
String constant are prefixed with L to specify an Unicode string (16 bit characters).

The main function is `ScanDir` which take the starting directory and a file mask. Example of call:

```
ScanDir(L"C:\\Users\\fpiette\\Documents", L"*.jpg");
```

`ScanDir` will scan the specified folder for all *files* and then scan again for all *directories*, calling `ScanDir` recursively. For each file, the size and filename are displayed (Of course you may display other properties like time stamp and attributes). For each directory, the name is displayed.

Basically, iterating a directory is done using Windows [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilew) and [FileNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilew).

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <Windows.h>

BOOL ScanDir(
    WCHAR* srcDir,
    WCHAR* fileMask)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE fh;
    BOOL more;
    WCHAR fromDir[MAX_PATH];
    BOOL found;
    _int64 fileSize;

    wcscpy(fromDir, srcDir);
    wcscat(fromDir, L"\\");
    wcscat(fromDir, fileMask);

    // First step: process files in current dir
    fh = FindFirstFile(fromDir, &fd);
    more = fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    found = FALSE;
    while (more) {
        // Ignore directories in first step
        if (0 == (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
            if (!found) {
                // For the first file found, display the title
                found = TRUE;
                wprintf(L"\nDirectory %s\n\n", srcDir);
            }
            fileSize = ((_int64)fd.nFileSizeHigh << 32) + fd.nFileSizeLow;
            // display file information
            wprintf(L"%12lld %s\n", fileSize, fd.cFileName);
        }
        more = FindNextFile(fh, &fd);
    }
    FindClose(fh);

    // Second step: recursively process subfolders
    wcscpy(fromDir, srcDir);
    wcscat(fromDir, L"\\*.*");
    fh = FindFirstFile(fromDir, &fd);
    more = fh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    while (more) {
        // Ignore files in second step
        if (0 != (fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
            // We have a directory, process it recursively
            if (wcsncmp(fd.cFileName, L".", 2) &&    // Ignore current directory "."
                wcsncmp(fd.cFileName, L"..", 3)) {   // Ignore parent directory ".."
                wcscpy(fromDir, srcDir);
                wcscat(fromDir, L"\\");
                wcscat(fromDir, fd.cFileName);
                if (!ScanDir(fromDir, fileMask))
                    return 0;
            }
        }
        more = FindNextFile(fh, &fd);
    }
    FindClose(fh);

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    // Change console output to unicode 16 bit (default is OEM)
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    ScanDir(L"C:\\Users\\fpiette\\Documents", L"*.jpg");
    return 0;
}
```